# How to create Excel or Windows Msg Box using COM in Python?

Tags: python, vba, com, pywin32

Is there a way to get pywin32 to generate a VBA-style MsgBox in Excel, if not, perhaps the Windows equivalent?

I tried:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.MsgBox('foo')
```

but it gives the error below:

```
AttributeError: Excel.Application.MsgBox
```

Comment: For future reference saying what the error is could be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, It's COM, so it gives a generic error: AttributeError: Excel.Application.MsgBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can use win32api:

```
import win32api

from win32con import MB_SYSTEMMODAL

response = win32api.MessageBox(0, "Did you hear the Buzzer?", "Buzzer Test", 4, MB_SYSTEMMODAL)
```

MB_SYSTEMMODAL is used for telling the system to show a message above all other applications.